# Python: Is the module of a class a class itself?

Tags: python, oop

Question says it all.

F.e.
when you refer to an object with a class of the bge.types-module which would then read like bge.types.class.

Comment: Question does not say it all... Please elaborate a bit more. Also, is this about a specific language?

Comment: What does that even mean? What language? For example, in `Java`, `Object.getClass` returns a `Class<?>`. `m` is an *instance* of a class in `MyClass m = new MyClass()`.

Comment: Lol I wrote it wrong sorry. Language is Python I thought it was posted in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, although the module type itself is defined in C, it is a type just like any other and you can even subclass from it:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ModuleType
<class 'module'>
>>> class C(types.ModuleType):
    def foo(self):
        print("hello")


>>> my_module = C('my_module')
>>> my_module
<module 'my_module'>
>>>
```

Uses for this are strictly limited though I did for fun once write some code that would replace a class in `sys.modules` with a subclass instance that was a copy of the original module but with support for `getattr`.

In normal use there is precisely one module type: individual modules are instances of the module type not separate types in their own right.

Comment: This essentially says that the module type is a type. The question asked whether modules themselves are classes though..

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I see there is a little discussion over this topic, glad I asked it :) Btw I just read about metaclasses this is were this question becomes especially interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No, modules are not classes. The class construct is essentially used to define a type, and you can instantiate types by calling them. You can not however call modules, and you cannot instantiate them at all.

You can think about modules as singletons: There can only ever exist a single instance of a module.

Modules can contain members that are types though, so essentially modules can contain classes.

Comment: You can instantiate them: `types.ModuleType('foo')`

Comment: @Duncan That creates a new module though. Modules themselves are not types, and you cannot instantiate them. If you import e.g. `sys`, you cannot instantiate `sys`. So no, modules are not types/classes just like actual int objects are not types/classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I see there is a little discussion over this topic, glad I asked it :) Btw I just read about metaclasses this is were this question becomes especially interesting.

Comment: @Jonathan For meta classes, check [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949) on the topic.

Comment: @Jonathan, the discussion is more about the meaning of words. I completely agree with poke that you cannot create an instance from an existing module because a module is an instance not a type, but I was pointing out that you can create instantiate a module which is one interpretation of what he said was impossible.

tl;dr: You need to be very precise to avoid ambiguity when discussing these issues.

Comment: @Duncan Nvm I also didnt know that you can instantiate a module like this.